# Where does duplicity store the key that it creates?

Tags: gpg, duplicity

I started a backup via duplicity without giving it any options. I haven't created any GPG keys myself, so when I ran duplicity, it asked me for a passphrase, then created a key, and successfully backed-up (to BackBlaze B2) with encryption and compression.

Good, but I don't know where the key is stored. Thus if my drive dies then I won't be able to restore the backup. `gpg -k` gives no output. Where's the key hiding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your (secret) key does exist then it is in the secret keyring of the user used to create the key. That user's keyrings are in a directory named '.gnupg' which is in that user's home directory.

So the secret key would be here for the user that created it:

```
~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

However, based on what you wrote, chances are duplicity just used a symmetric key which only consists of the passphrase you entered.

Reference : https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg

Comment: Haha! I was thinking that GPG was symmetric. (I'm really unfamiliar with crypto ^^;) OK, so in other words, duplicity probably encrypted via a deterministic cipher whose sole argument/secret was the passphrase that I gave, and it doesn't use keys nor entropy at all?

Comment: Forgot to mention: my ~/.gnupg directory does not contain a secring.gpg file.

Comment: This may shed some light concerning using Duplicity with a symmetric key: https://serverfault.com/questions/173767/how-can-i-use-duplicity-with-a-symmetric-key

Comment: thanks. That article confirms my hypothesis: "[if you're not using `--encrypt-key`, then] you're using symmetric encryption and the secret key consists of your passphrase exclusively."